# What is the definition of a mathematical point?

Tags: geometry

A [point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28geometry%29) is defined in the elements as that which have no parts, but what does this mean? There is nothing in the physical world that doesn't have an extension. You can't say a point is primitive notion because primitive notions are for objects which fall under our senses but mathematical points don't. So how to define a mathematical point?

Comment: A point is an element of a special set called a space. It has no further meaning in physics other than as an abstraction for things that are so small that we can approximate their size away.

Comment: What is the definition of a dog?  It's said that a dog is a mammal, but there is nothing in the reptile kingdom that is a mammal.  How can this be?  (If you've missed the, err, point, try reading "dog" as "point", "mammal" as "thing with no extent" and "reptile kingdom" as "physical world".)

Comment: if you have 2 points of a common 3D space with their positions at a the same time, draw 2 tangent spheres of half distance radius centered on the 2 points and take the minimal intersection between them. In the ( classical ) physical world , it is the exact and unique point of zero gravity assuming you are in a big void and that the masses at A and B are equal. The slightest deviation is sufficient to get moving. With modern physics, it's a quite more complicated ; it's impossible to set the perfect inital conditions.

Comment: @igael: I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. We don't have tangent spheres in physics or minimal intersections or zero gravity. You can't define something that doesn't exist by using three other, more complicated things, that also don't exist. Everything in physics is defined by reference to finite objects. Even the OP had this figured out to some extent when he said that there is nothing in the physical world that has no extension. The reason we are using mathematical points is because they are useful approximations for things we actually do have.

Comment: @CuriousOne : strictly speaking, you're right but be aware of QFT nihilism. As I tried to say, it is possible to well define a point in classical physics , ie the Lagrange points. Such point becomes blurred and inflates only because the uncertainty of the initial settings

Comment: @igael: We don't have points in classical physics, either. Where did you see a point in Newton's laws?

Comment: @CuriousOne : a center of mass is a point in Newton mechanics ( cf central forces )

Comment: @CuriousOne: you say a point in mathematics is defined as an element of space( or more precisely metric space) but how does this connect to euclid's definition and also the physical world.Thanks

Comment: @igael: A center of mass is not a physical object. We try to make that clear in high school physics by showing objects which are void of matter where their center of mass is.

Comment: @CuriousOne : semantic approach ... a location with particular properties , even if relative , is a physical object in my syntax

Comment: @moho: The only connection of points to the physical world is that sometimes the movements of real objects can be approximated by the movement of their center of mass. We clearly spell this out when we teach physics properly, but like with many basic definitions in physics students are insensitive to these core facts of physics, the science. It's not their fault and it's not the teacher's fault, either. We can't teach physics hands on (i.e. with enough experiments) to bring this home and for students passing the next test is far more important than ontology.

Comment: @igael: The only relevant semantics in physics is experimental. Don't fall for the theory cool aid. If it's not experimentally tested, it's not physics. Points can not be experimentally tested. They are simply mathematical crutches that we use for trivial approximations.

Comment: @CuriousOne: what about Euclid definition, thanks.

Comment: @moho: Euclid is an early mathematician. He is not a physicist and he is not talking about physics. You can do all of Euclidean geometry without drawing a single figure, anyway, that's just not how it's being taught in high school, either.

Answer (score 1):

In Euclid's geometry a point is taken as a given in much the way you describe. It is essentially up to the geometer to gain an appreciation of the idea. Riemann (n.d.) refers to similar aspects, stating:
"It is known that geometry assumes, as things given, both the notion of space and the first principles of constructions in space. She gives definitions of them which are merely nominal, while the true determinations appear in the form of axioms. The relation of these assumptions remains consequently in darkness; we neither perceive whether and how far their connection is necessary, nor a priori, whether it is possible. 
From Euclid to Legendre (to name the most famous of modern reforming geometers) this darkness was cleared up neither by mathematicians nor by such philosophers as concerned themselves with it."
He later finds (p.149)
"[I]t is therefore quite likely that the metric relations of space [(meaning forms of measurement, loosely speaking)] in the infinitely small do not agree with the assumptions of geometry, and in fact one would have to accept [an alternative theorem] as soon as the phenomena can thereby be explained in a simpler way."
No further progress in this matter has been achieved in more recent times. In Hilbert’s ‘Foundations of Geometry’ (1971) the concepts of point, line, plane and the relation of betweenness remain simple (Goheen in Hilbert 1971).
The bother in your concern is that is assumes an anthropocentric idea of space, which according to Kant is not one that allows us to get as concepts properly because we see the world through the 'lens of the mind'. Von Neumann (1996) identifies that contemporary mathematics finds its roots in our observations of the world (no matter the level of abstraction that results).
In that context you question is problematic. To answer further would require swimming to the bottom of the pool of philosophy, a very dark place indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer: It depends on the context. Different areas of mathematics use the notion of a point. Here is a small sample:

1. In metric geometry, a point is an element of a [**metric space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).
2. In topology, a point is an element of a [**topological space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space).
3. In [**axiomatic geometry**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry#Axiomatic_systems) a la David Hilbert, the notion of a point is a primitive notion, left undefined. What is defined in the axiomatic setting is a collection of primitives (say, points and lines) and various relations (say, incidence relations), satisfying various axioms.
4. In algebraic geometry, a **geometric point** is a certain morphism between schemes (I'd rather not go any further into this).
5. In many areas of mathematics (say, real analysis, convex geometry, etc.) a point is synonymous with an element of ${\mathbb R}^n$.